# How can I create a word (.docx) document if not found using python and write in it?

Tags: python, python-docx

How can I create a word (.docx) document if not found using python and write in it?

I certainly cannot do either of the following:

```
file = open(file_name, 'r')
file = open(file_name, 'w')
```

or, to create or append if found:

```
f = open(file_name, 'a+')
```

Also I cannot find any related info in python-docx documentation at:

https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

**NOTE:**

I need to create an automated report via python with text and pie charts, graphs etc.

Comment: You can open a file in `'x'` mode: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29295654/2988730

Comment: why can't you do `f = open(file_name, 'a+')` can  you please explain

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari 'a+' is for simple files, .docx file is a binary file which has something like 'rb' intead of 'r' for normal files. I may be wrong, what do you say?

Comment: @Yugandhar. Because a word docx file is a binary zip archive containing, among other things, a bunch of XML files inside it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist 'x' cannot open/create a word file I guess.

Comment: @Piyush. It most certainly can.

Comment: @MadPhysicist it seems to work, but the docx file it makes is corrupted.

Comment: Did you open it in binary mode?

Comment: I've added a section about appending to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the safest way to open (and truncate) a new file for writing is using [`'xb'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) mode. `'x'` will raise a [`FileExistsError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#FileExistsError) if the file is already there. `'b'` is necessary because a word document is fundamentally a binary file: it's a zip archive with XML and other files inside it. You can't compress and decompress a zip file if you convert bytes through character encoding.

[`Document.save`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#docx.document.Document.save) accepts streams, so you can pass in a file object opened like that to save your document.

Your work-flow could be something like this:

```
doc = docx.Document(...)
...
# Make your document
...
with open('outfile.docx', 'xb') as f:
    doc.save(f)
```

It's a good idea to use `with` blocks instead of raw `open` to ensure the file gets closed properly even in case of an error.

In the same way that you can't simply write to a Word file directly, you can't append to it either. The way to "append" is to open the file, load the [`Document`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#docx.document.Document) object, and then write it back, overwriting the original content. Since the word file is a zip archive, it's very likely that appended text won't even be at the end of the XML file it's in, much less the whole docx file:

```
doc = docx.Document('file_to_append.docx')
...
# Modify the contents of doc
...
doc.save('file_to_append.docx')
```

Keep in mind that the python-docx library may not support loading some elements, which may end up being permanently discarded when you save the file this way.

Answer (score 0):

**Looks like I found an answer:**

> The important point here was to create a new file, if not found, or
>   otherwise edit the already present file.

```
import os
from docx import Document 

#checking if file already present and creating it if not present
if not os.path.isfile(r"file_path"):

    #Creating a  blank document
    document = Document()

    #saving the blank document
    document.save('file_name.docx')

#------------editing the file_name.docx now------------------------

#opening the existing document
document = Document('file_name.docx')

#editing it
document.add_heading("hello world" , 0)

#saving document in the end
document.save('file_name.docx')
```

**Further edits/suggestions are welcome.**

Comment: This is not immune from race conditions.

Comment: @MadPhysicist can you suggest an edit, for exactly where does it goes wrong?

Comment: The edit is I'm my answer. The race condition is between checking `isfile` and opening said file.