# Why does open mode 'w' but not 'x' trigger permission denied error ONLY after compiling as exe in windows?

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, permission-denied, python-docx

I was trying to use `python-docx` to create a word doc. The below code worked when running in python IDE, but after I compiled it to an exe using PyInstaller, I got a `[Errno 13] Permission Denied error` when trying to run it. I'm on Win 10.

```
from docx import Document
document = Document()
document.add_heading('My Header', 0)
document.save('save_path.docx')
```

Things I tried based on the common answers on StackOverflow, but to no avail:

- running exe with admin modes
- running admin mode cmd and powershell and executing the exe directly.
- running `open('save_path.docx', 'wb')` also caused the same error.

What eventually worked was adding `with open(save_path, 'x') as f: f.writelines(['test'])` before the `document.save()` command. Strangely, `with open(save_path, 'w')...` caused the permission denied error. So, something about the `'x'` mode seems to make the .exe behave.

Final code that worked, inspired by [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295654/what-does-python3-open-x-mode-do), `'x': open for exclusive creation, failing if the file already exists`:

```
from docx import Document

with open(save_path, 'x') as f:
    f.writelines(['test'])

document = Document()
document.add_heading('My Header', 0)
document.save('save_path.docx')
```

I didn't even need any admin rights to write to that file.

Can anyone explain why the `'x'` mode is the only mode that works? It feels like it might be a security feature (not a bug!) where the python exe is not allowed to modify existing files but can create and then modify a file, which sounds much safer.