# How do I not overwrite my save data? (pickle in python)

Tags: python, pickle

While using pickle, I came across a problem (for me) where it overwrites the save data with the default save data when the script is open up. Is there a way to detect if anything is in the file?

```
import pickle

savedata = ['tutorialisntfinished', 'tutorialisfinished', 'level1isntfinished', 'level1isfinished', 'level2isntfinished', 'level2isfinished', 'bossfightisntfinished', 'bossfightisfinished']
pickle.dump(savedata, open('savedata.json', 'wb'))
```

And then I have some scripts that detect scenes and change variables.

I have a system to change save data by removing the (example)isntfinished from the list called savedata. All of this works, but When you reopen the script, it resets it. Anyone have a fix / solution for this?

Comment: "where it overwrites the save data with the default save data when the script is open up." Well, why are you writing to the save data file at that point in the program? Why not only write to the file... when... the user wants to save?

Comment: Also, please don't use the `.json` file extension if you aren't going to write JSON data. `pickle` does not produce JSON. If you want JSON, use `json`. You probably don't have a real use case for `pickle`, and it can introduce security risks. `pickle` isn't for storing data with a curated structure; it's for preserving existing data within the program, including class structure. Think of it more like an emulator save-state, rather than a game-provided save file.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
try:
    with open("fname", "xb") as fout:
        #Work with your open file
except FileExistsError:
    # Your error handling goes here
```

I can recommend you reading [What does python3 open "x" mode do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295654/what-does-python3-open-x-mode-do)